# Phonegap FileReader readAsText returns null but readAsDataURL works

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, zip, fileapi

I'm using Phonegap to download an archive, unzip it, then read the files. It's all working until I try and read the files as text. If I use `readAsDataURL()` then I get a whole heap of stuff logged to the console.

```
function( file ) {
    console.log(file);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function( evt ) {
        console.log( evt.target.result );
    };                      
    reader.readAsDataURL( file );
}
```

If I use `readAsText()` I get `null`. The files range from 300KB to 1.4MB, but all files return `null` in the console.

```
reader.readAsText( file );
```

Why would one function return something and the other be null? Is there a limit on the text size it can read?

This is the `file` object that I'm logging before creating `reader`, that I'm applying the functions to (I've shortened the file name):

```
{
    "name":"categories.json",
    "fullPath":"/var/mobile/.../Documents/data/file.json",
    "type":null,
    "lastModifiedDate":1380535318000,
    "size":382456
}
```

And this is the evt object for `readAsText()`:

```
{
    "type":"loadend",
    "bubbles":false,
    "cancelBubble":false,
    "cancelable":false,
    "lengthComputable":false,
    "loaded":0,
    "total":0,
    "target":{
        "fileName":"/var/mobile/.../Documents/data/file.json",
        "readyState":2,
        "result":"null",
        "error":null,
        "onloadstart":null,
        "onprogress":null,
        "onload":null,
        "onerror":null,
        "onabort":null
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I've seen in the W3C spec for the File API that result would only be set to null if an error had occured. But I tried adding a `reader.onerror()` function, but that wasn't getting called.

> If an error occurs during reading the blob parameter, set readyState
>   to DONE and set result to null. Proceed to the error steps.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsText

Comment: This is killing me right now too. Seen some strange stuff out there. Some involve changing var names. Is there a namespace conflict in file or result or something?

Comment: I've had to stash this code for the time being but I'll be coming back to it soon. I'll try and use really unique var names for each stage to make sure nothing is clashing.

Comment: In my case I think I was grabbing a fileEntry instead of a file. Had to do `fileEntry.file(function(fileObject){ ...reader.readAsText(fileObject); })`

Comment: Took me a while to get around to it but that was it @ErikReppen, you should submit that as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have been grabbing the fileEntry instead of a fileObject. Assuming file was actually fileEntry, try this:

```
var
    fileEntry = file, //for example clarity - assumes file from OP's file param
    reader = new FileReader()
;

fileEntry.file( doSomethingWithFileObject );//gets the fileObject passed to it

function doSomethingWithFileObject(fileObject){

    reader.onloadend = function(e){
        doSomething(e.target.result); //assumes doSomething defined elsewhere
    }

    var fileAsText = reader.readAsText(fileObject);
}
```

Definitely an API that screams for cruft reduction.